# executeQuery only working for queries when mySQL commands are uppercase?

Tags: java, mysql

I am developing a two-tier java application that basically displays mySQL database results in a JTable in a GUI. The mySQL queries are typed in by the user in a textArea and then an 'execute command' button is pressed and the mySQL results corresponding to that command simply appear in the JTable.

The problem I am running into is when I try to type in a query such as "SELECT * FROM bikes WHERE COST=10000;" everything works as expected and results are returned. However, if I type in "select * from bikes where cost=10000;", no results are returned and basically nothing happens, not even getting an error. I tried running 'toUpperCase()' on the query, which didn't fix the problem.

I was wondering what might be causing this problem? I am aware that mySQL is not case sensitive, so it should work even if my SELECT is lower case... 
The code below is a snippet of the area that might be causing the problem.

```
public void setQuery(String query) throws SQLException, IllegalStateException{
        if(!connectedToDatabase)
            throw new IllegalStateException("Not Connected to Database");


        String firstWord = query.substring(0, 6);
        if(firstWord.toUpperCase().equals("SELECT")){           
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
        }
        else if(firstWord.toUpperCase().equals("INSERT") || firstWord.toUpperCase().equals("DELETE") || firstWord.toUpperCase().equals("UPDATE")){
            statement2.executeUpdate(query);
        }

        metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();

        resultSet.last();
        numberOfRows = resultSet.getRow();
        fireTableStructureChanged();
    }
```

Comment: I would log and see what firstWord is. I guess it could be issue of space than case.

Comment: firstWord, is not the problem... it simply gets the first word of the query and I tested that it works properly... as long as the "SELECT" or the "INSERT" is uppercase.

Comment: Are you sure the if(firstWord.toUpperCase().equals("SELECT")) statement is where your issue is?  Try String firstWord = query.substring(0, 6).toUpperCase();  That will avoid you having to repeat thesame statement multiple times later (both more maintainable and more efficient).  Output this result (to a debug file / console / etc) to see what the string looks like - i.e. to be certain you have SELECT and nothing else.  Can you also show us the code used to make up statement/statement2; it could be that the program is getting past the IF statement and the issue's elsewhere.

Comment: Then can you check control going to corresponding block, either if (or) else, just to make sure block also being executed or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Try using [equalsIgnoreCase](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29) instead of straight `equals`.
- If you don't know if the code is getting into an `if` block, try adding some logging into that block.
- Assuming it is getting into the block, the query is likely causing the problem.